# page being called twice

Tags: php, html

I've noticed some strange behavior with my page being called twice.

I have the following HTML in the footer of my page:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="modal-link"><img id="modal-img" src="#" style="width:100%;"></a>
</div>
```

The code is part of a modal box that gets used on several pages and the href element gets set after document ready when needed.  I've noticed that every page that includes this footer code gets called twice but if I comment out the  line it doesn't.

Is there a reason this link gets followed automatically causing the same page to load twice?

Comment: It’s because of the src of the img element – `#` is refering to an (empty) anchor in the same document, and so some browsers request the same URL as the document itself has again trying to download the image resource.

Comment: Is this intended behavior...the link isn't even being clicked. It happens when the page loads...

Comment: What’s that got to do with the link? Browser sees a `#` as `src` attribute for the image, according to the rules for resolving relative URLs that leads to the same absolute URL as the document has – and so the browser requests it in trying to get image data to display …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove src="#" and it will work fine I guess.